# proxy - linked system

Tags: rigging, linked-data, proxies

I am wondering how the proxy system is working. I have few questions:

**A)** If I have a riged model and make proxy in other blend file the controllers. Then I update the rig and adding controllers - the linked file will be updated with new controllers ? Even the old-one are proxies?

**B)** Is there some possibility to change the linked blend file from example from Rig_version_01 to Rig_version_02 without damage the completed animation ?

**C)** Can I freely changing and animating the textures if they are driven by custom property trough proxy ? (like changing mix node fac)

Thank you very much